# Confusion concerning Cantor's theorem.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm a little confused about Cantor's theorem stating that the cardinality of a set cannot be equal to the cardinality of its power set.

Consider the power set of $\mathbb{N}$. Couldn't the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ be considered to be a subset of the union of the  sets $\mathbb{N^1}, \mathbb{N^2}, \mathbb{N^3}, \ldots$? All the sets are denumerable, and clearly the list of sets is denumerable, so shouldn't their union and thus an infinite subset of their union be denumerable, implying that the cardinality is the same as $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: when you say "couldn't it...?" what are you actually wishing to assert, in mathematical language?

Comment: I edited my question to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: Which of the sets ${\mathbb N}^k$ has as an element the set of all even natural numbers?

Comment: Similarly, sometimes we see claimed proofs that the set of reals is countable, but in fact showing only that the set of terminating decimals is countable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That union gives you only the finite subsets.  There are indeed only countably many finite subsets of $\mathbb N$.

However, we should also note that the union you speak of gives you tuples, not subsets.  For example $(3,1,7)$ and $(1,7,3)$ are two different tuples, as are $(2,2,3)$ and $(2,3)$.  The sets $\{3,1,7\}$ and $\{1,7,3\}$ are the same, and the sets $\{2,2,3\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ are the same.

Cantor's theorem actually says the cardinality of a set is strictly less than the cardinality of its power set.

Comment: I'm aware of that, which is why I specified that the power set is a subset of the described set. I should have specified that I was considering the power set to be the set of equivalence classes on the larger set given the appropriate equivalence relation. But, the first reason you gave mostly clears it up for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is at work only a small misunderstanding concerning the notion of subset in the sense of infinite subset. I will offer a proof as follows, which I hope helps as it is without explicit reference to infinity.

*Theorem*: Let $X:=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and denote by $P(X)$ the set of all subsets of $X$, then $P(X)>X$. (or equivalently, if $X$ is an $n$-element set, then $P(X)= 2^n$).

Let $f: P(X) \rightarrow D$ when $D := \{s_1,...,s_n\}$, $n \in \mathbb N$.

For each $S \subseteq X$, set $f(S)=(s_1,...,s_n)$ where $s_i=1$ if $x_i$ is in $S$, $0$ if otherwise.

Note that $|D|=2^n$ (or $n$-many copies (products) of elements of $X$).

Proof that $f$ is one to one:
1) Let $S,M \subseteq X$ with $S \neq M$, then $U \nsubseteq V$, so there is some $i, 1<i<n$ such that $x_i$ is in $S$ but not in $M$ (i.e., takes on the value of 1 if in $S$ and $0$ if in $M$. More precisely, for $f(S)$, $f(x_i) =1$ for $x_i \in S$ but $f(x_i) = 0$ for $x_i \in M$. Therefore $ f(S) \neq f(M)$.

Proof that $f$ is onto:
2) Let $(s_1,...,s_n) \in D$ as above. Take $x_i \in S \iff x_i =1$. Clearly, $f(S) = (s_1,...,s_n)$. Thus $f$ is bijective, and $|P(X)|=|D|$, where $|D|$ is $n$-many copies of elements of $X$.